# US I-130 denied under INA 204-c, will this affect my Employment Visa Application to Ireland?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, ireland

I originally applied for a permanent resident green card in the US back in '08 with my then spouse, but due to the fact that we were having marital issues, she sabotaged the interview, and I got denied the green card, but I had no idea what transpired in the interview because we were interviewed separately. We eventually divorced. I got remarried in 2012, and reapplied for a new I-130 and I-485, and this time got denied because I didn't show enough evidence that the previous marriage wasn't a sham. This blindsided me because I originally thought I was denied due to RFE, and couldn't gather enough evidence to prove my case that original marriage wasn't a sham just going bad, and because I didn't know the law and didn't have a lawyer the first time, I didn't appeal the original decision. I'm currently appeal this new denial, but I recently got a job in Ireland, and i'm wondering if these denials will affect my irish visa application negatively?

Answer (score 1):

**Perhaps.** The Irish might ask for prior rejections/deportations. Even if they do not ask, they might know anyway because of information sharing agreements.

Anything which puts your credibility in doubt will be negative. A denial is bad, being caught in a lie is even worse. So tell the truth and hope for the best.